# Administrator access

Tags: 12.04

How do I know that I have administrator's access on Ubuntu 12.04 and how do I stop the incessant prompts that always need my authorization to be able to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to having admin access through `sudo` here are some pointers:

The file `/etc/sudoers` contains the rules of when some user can use sudo and when not. 
An important point highlighted by [0xc0000022l](https://askubuntu.com/users/11316/0xc0000022l) is that you shouldn't edit /etc/sudoers directly but should use `sudo visudo` instead. That and more, useful information can be found on the man page:

`man sudoers`

On standard installs, membership of group admin will get you admin access. You can find out your group membership on the commandline by issuing `id` (or using a GUI 'user management' to see what groups you belong to).

- Since you are talking about the 'incessant prompts', I would suggest to get used to them. Attempts to disable them is typically not a good idea. You can lengthen the time you will be allowed to use sudo for. I suggest to only use sudo form one terminal and not from several (since you would have to type in your password in all of those terminals).
- If you are undertaking some more involved administration requiring you to be root for many things, I suggest you switch users:

  `sudo su -`

This will make you root in that session. Whatever you do, I recommend you **do not make yourself root by default**. This will just results in more headache down the road (including the security holes associated with it).

Comment: you should point to `man sudoers` and also `visudo`. The latter mostly because of the sanity checking after editing, much like in `crontab -e`.

Comment: @0xC0000022L thank you - quite right, edited the post as you suggested.